# What is this game with a many-legged creature?

Tags: game-identification

My father-in-law took this screenshot from YouTube of a game my son wants, but he is notorious for not writing down the name of the game. Any ideas? Sorry for the picture quality.

[image: Many legged creature in a forest]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's the aptly-named Scorpion Simulator game, available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glutenfreegames.scorpionsimulator) and [iOS App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scorpion-simulator/id910831234).